# Dynamic dataset from MySQL query with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, chart.js

I am trying to create a dynamic dataset for my Chart.js project but I am having trouble, here is an example of the dataset pulled from `getpromorevenuechart.php`:

`[{"mmyy":"2019-12","promocode":"promo1","amount":"2776"},{"mmyy":"2020-01","promocode":"promo1","amount":"1245"},{"mmyy":"2020-01","promocode":"promo2","amount":"179"}`]

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    function getPromoRChartData() {
    var city = document.getElementById("cityselect").value;
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getpromorevenuechart.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {  city:city, },
        success: function(response) {
          //console.log (response);

          function collate(d) {
            return d.reduce(function(prev, cur, index) {
                var ret = {};
                for (var prop in cur) {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        ret[prop] = [];
                    } else {
                        ret[prop] = prev[prop];
                    }
                    ret[prop].push(cur[prop]);
                }
                return ret;
            }, {});
        }

          var reduced = collate(response);

var ctx = document.getElementById('promorChart').getContext('2d');

var chartColors = window.chartColors;
var color = Chart.helpers.color;

var fleetmChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: reduced.mmyy,
        datasets: [{
        label: reduced.promocode,
        data: reduced.amount,
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              stacked: false
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              stacked: false,
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return "$" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString();
                }
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        elements: {
        }
    }
});
```

But that code isn't displaying the way I want. The way I want this to look is like the following:

```
data: {
        labels: ["2019-12", "2020-01"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'promo 1',
            data: [2776, 1245]
        },
        {
            label: 'promo 2',
            data: [0, 179]
        }
        ]
    },
```

What it seems I need to do is create a for each type thing and I would also need to introduce a 0 for mm/yy when that promo isn't used. I am very unsure how to do all this. Can someone give me some direction and assist me in how to make this happen?

Edit:

Trying to incorporate `uminder`'s code below:

```
    function getPromoRChartData() {
    var city = document.getElementById("cityselect").value;
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getpromorevenuechart.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {  city:city, },
        success: function(response) {
const labels = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.mmyy))).sort();
const promocodes = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.promocode))).sort();
const datasets = promocodes.map(pc => ({ label: pc, data: []}));
labels.forEach(l => {    
    for (let pc of promocodes) {
      let city = response.find(c => c.mmyy == l && c.promocode == pc);
        datasets.find(ds => ds.label == pc).data.push(city ? city.amount : 0);
    }
});

var dynlabels = JSON.stringify(labels);
var dyndatasets = JSON.stringify(datasets, undefined, "  ");

console.log (dynlabels);
console.log (dyndatasets);

var ctx = document.getElementById('promorChart').getContext('2d');

var chartColors = window.chartColors;
var color = Chart.helpers.color;

var promorChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [dynlabels],
        datasets: [{
            dyndatasets
        }
        ]
    },

    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              stacked: false
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              stacked: false,
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return "$" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString();
                }
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        elements: {
        }
    }
});
```

does not render the graph correctly at all, here is a screen shot of the graph rendered (using the above input data):

[image]

and here is the console output:

```
    ["2019-12","2020-01"]
    success — Script Element 2:1382[
      {
        "label": "promo1",
        "data": [
          "2776",
          "1245"
        ]

  },
  {
    "label": "promo2",
    "data": [
      0,
      "179"
    ]
  }
]
```

If I remove the [{}] around `dyndatasets` I get the error:

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

and if I remove the brackets from `dynlabels` this happens:

[image]

Oddly enough... if I copy directly from the console and past in the fields it works, so I don't know what gives? Is it like a formatting error?

Comment: what do you mean by "create a `for each` type thing"? where did you get that info from?

Comment: I don't know maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code sample that illustrates how to convert the `response` into the data (`labels` and `datasets`) required by chart.js.

```js
const response = [ 
   { 
      "mmyy":"2019-12",
      "promocode":"promo1",
      "amount":"2776"
   },
   { 
      "mmyy":"2020-01",
      "promocode":"promo1",
      "amount":"1245"
   },
   { 
      "mmyy":"2020-01",
      "promocode":"promo2",
      "amount":"179"
   }
];

const labels = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.mmyy))).sort();
const promocodes = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.promocode))).sort();
const datasets = promocodes.map(pc => ({ label: pc, data: []}));
labels.forEach(l => {    
    for (let pc of promocodes) {
     let city = response.find(c => c.mmyy == l && c.promocode == pc);
        datasets.find(ds => ds.label == pc).data.push(city ? Number(city.amount) : 0);
    }
});

console.log("labels: " + JSON.stringify(labels));
console.log("datasets: " + JSON.stringify(datasets, undefined, "  "));
```

Please have a look at the following [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6rn9cp10/)

Comment: There seems to a be a strange formatting error, check above and please advise.

Comment: I updated my answer and corrected an error in my sample code. I now convert `amount` to a `number`.

Comment: Still not working, it's also the label, as you can see on the bottom it is not displaying correctly,

Comment: You must not use `JSON.stringify` in the real code, I did this only to show nice output when logging to the console (see https://jsfiddle.net/cer9fwum/).

Comment: Can you help me add colors to that as well, from this dataset of colors?

Comment: Please have a loog at https://jsfiddle.net/6rn9cp10/ that uses `chartjs-plugin-colorschemes` (see also https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/).

Comment: One more question for you, I had to change the date format from YYYY-MM to m/y - regardless of how I output it in my PHP your code is misordering the dates, how can I order it?

Comment: last one I promise!

Comment: @Tony: Please create a new question for this new issue, possibly with sample data of the new format. This will make it easier to provide a clear answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962374/chart-js-show-data-in-chronological-order there you go, could you please upvote my questions too?